# How can i make rating start with fontawesome 5 svg?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I'm making rating star with fontawesome 5 but unable to make.

What i tried

```css
rating-overall{padding: 10px !important; padding-top: 20px; width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 0px; line-height: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.32); cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 12px;}
.rating-overall .fa-star{ font-size: 18px;}
.rating-overall p{ margin-bottom: 0px;}

.star-parent{ width: 130px; position: relative;}
.gray-star{ color:#797979; position: absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; z-index: -1;}
.yellow-star{ color:#dbb403; width: 62px; overflow: hidden !important;}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>


<div class="p-relative star-parent float-left ml-2">
                            <div class="gray-star">
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="yellow-star">
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I want like below image:-

[image]

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` to yellow stars container

Comment: another solution would be to set `display: flex` on the yellow stars container (and doesn't hurt to also set it to grey container so they behave the same)

Comment: @cloned it sould be added to both container in this case, because flex will disable whitespace between inline element so adding it to one container won't be good.

Answer (score 0):

just add `white-space:nowrap` and change `width: 82px;` to this class `.yellow-star` it will works

```css
rating-overall{padding: 10px !important; padding-top: 20px; width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 0px; line-height: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.32); cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 12px;}
.rating-overall .fa-star{ font-size: 18px;}
.rating-overall p{ margin-bottom: 0px;}

.star-parent{ width: 130px; position: relative;}
.gray-star{ color:#797979; position: absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; z-index: -1;}
.yellow-star{ color:#dbb403; width: 82px; overflow: hidden !important;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>


<div class="p-relative star-parent float-left ml-2">
                            <div class="gray-star">
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="yellow-star">
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```